# Why can't one of my files be copied?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, file-transfer

I have this mp4 video file on one of my portable hard drives, which could not be copied.

It could be played perfectly directly from my portable hard drive but when I copy it to my internal hard drive, I will encounter an error something like `Could not read file, I/O device error, can't complete the request. Error code: 1117` on Windows 7 (The error message is not in the exact words when it was displayed, because I run a Chinese system. But the gist is there.), when around 112 MB of this file is processed. The file has 249MB in total.

And I also tried on Mac, and tried using `FastCopy` on windows, the same problem occurs.

Is there a way to rescue this file?

Comment: Seems like it's time to run a `chkdsk /R` and probably replace the hard drive.

Comment: Yes, let me try `chkdsk /R`. I am thinking of replacing it, but I want this file back..

Comment: FYI, looking up that error code on UK system you get: "The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error." you might have some luck googling that.

Comment: @WernerHenze `chkdsk /R` did the trick, thanks, you may answer it, and I will accept that, for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the hard disk is defect and should be replaced as soon as possible.

You might try to run a `chkdsk /R` to recover bad sectors.